# Best way to show that there are many viewable photos for mobile app?

Tags: mobile, image, app, carousel

I'm working on a design for an application that shows used cars. On the car details page, some cars may have many photos, and I'm not sure how I should show that there are more/many viewable photos.

I was thinking of using circles in a carousel like this,

[image: car with circle icons]

but if a car has 30 photos, I wouldn't want it to have 30 little circles. I also considered using arrows on either side of the image, but I'm just personally not a fan.

What is the best way to show that the user can view more photos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A carousel is a tried and trusted metaphor which has been around for a long time, and you can carousel through all 30 thumbnails if you want. Users will be familiar with this metaphor.

The Facebook example shown by @Grafix Guru is not a carousel (clicking takes you to another page where the images are stacked vertically in a scrollable page), however the Facebook example is still a very neat solution, which many people will be familiar with.

You just need to decide if you want to copy Facebook (they do say imitation is form a flattery).

Alternatively you could consider a hybrid solution, combining a carousel with the +30 text, as this will communicate how many photos there are in the carousel.

Hopefully you are considering usability testing multiple design solutions with real users, rather than just one design solution.

Comment: Thanks!  Helpful to know that carousels can sometimes have 30 images! I will definitely be doing usability testing!

Answer (score 2):

Follow the Facebook method.

Assume if you have 20 photos to show and you have space of accommodating 5 photos then add '+15' on the the black overlay of the 5th photo thumbnail image.

Refer the attached  screenshot for more info [image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Is that also how it looks on facebook mobile?  I don't use the mobile app so I can't check.  I know that's how it looks on the website.

Comment: Yes, please try